# Fatal error when trying to get product price in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm doing simple popup where you can see price of product with installment. I write a simple script. It work as I want. There is a buttun (popup) on product page. Everything is fine! BUT main page of site is giving fatal error. Why it so I do'nt know. Please help! I am using WordPress v5.5.1 and WooCommerce v4.5.2

```
    <?php
                  
       $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id());
       $price = $product->get_price();
       
        $deadline = 12;
        $rate = 25;

        $rate_sum = ($price/ 100) * $rate;
        $total_sum = $price+ $rate_sum;
        $base_per_month = $total_sum / $deadline;
 ?>
<div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
<div class="modal-content position-relative">
<div class="modal-header"><strong>Купить в рассрочку</strong></div>
<div class="modal-body">
<h3>Через MegaDream</h3>
<table class="table">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="col" style="width: 33%;">Оплата за месяц</th>
<th class="col" style="width: 33%;">Срок (месяц)</th>
<th class="col" style="width: 33%;">Общая сумма</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td><b id="month_credit" style="color: #fe4f19; font-weight: 800;"><?php echo round($base_per_month); ?></b></td>
<td style="text-align: left;"><b style="color: #fe4f19; font-weight: 800;">12</b></td>
<td><b id="total_credit" style="color: #fe4f19; font-weight: 800;"><?php echo round($total_sum); ?></b></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
По вопросам получения товаров в рассрочку, звоните по номеру <strong>+998(99) 351-71-40</strong>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer"><a class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #457f33; color: white;" href="tel:+998993517140" type="button">Позвонить</a></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: _“Why it so I do'nt know.”_ - why it so, _you_ need to go an find out! We can not look into your system from the outside. Whenever you get a 500 Internal Server error, then the _first_ thing you have to do, is go and check what the error log has to say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps your $product is empty. You should check it before an action:

```
if(!empty($product)){
  $price = $product->get_price(); // and so on
}
```

Comment: Hi bro! It works! Thank you! But it does not work correct for variable products. It gets only minimal price not what I choose. How can I solve it?